# Adding vertical child divs inside a parent div (both fixed width) with dynamic horizontal scrollbar at parent level

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to add a layout where the parent div has a fixed width which contains child columns (as divs). The children are of fixed width can be dynamically added and removed, however, if there are more children than that can fit inside the fixed-width parent div, I want a horizontal scroll bar to show. But I am unable to get that working.

JSFIDDLE: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vwz9e7L/)

```
.newFilterItemsBox {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 690px;
    height: 572px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    flex-direction: column;
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
.newFilterSelectionColumnContainer {
    width: 685px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left:-4px;
    height: 500px;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.newFilterSelectionColumn {
    border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
    height: 508px;  
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:auto;
    z-index:100000;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.newFilterSelectionColumnContainer`